# How to do something twice in different branches in haml

Tags: ruby, haml

I have code somewhat like this:

```
- say_hi = proc do |to_who|
  .himessage
    Hi
    = to_who
.foo
  .bar
    = say_hi.call "bob"
  = say_hi.call "joe"
```

The output I want would be:

```
<div class='foo'>
  <div class='bar'>
    <div class='himessage'>
      Hi
      bob
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='himessage'>
    Hi
    joe
  </div>
</div>
```

Instead I get:

```
<div class='himessage'>
  Hi
  bob
</div>
<div class='himessage'>
  Hi
  joe
</div>
<div class='foo'>
  <div class='bar'>
    2
  </div>
  1
</div>
```

It seems that the text is getting inserted back where the proc was defined, instead of where it's being called. I do not have a good enough understanding of haml's internals to know why this is happening, and I care about is: **How do I get the desired output while keeping my code dry?**

<sup><sub>Note: In my actual project the equivelent to the `say_hi` proc is much longer and more complicated, and so simply repeating it twice would be very ugly. The above is simply the easiest case that would cause this problem without an obvious solution.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`capture_haml`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#capture_haml-instance_method), otherwise Haml will write directly to the output when the proc is called:

```
- say_hi = proc do |to_who|
  - capture_haml do
    .himessage
      Hi
      = to_who
.foo
  .bar
    = say_hi.call "bob"
  = say_hi.call "joe"
```

Comment: I had just gotten started hacking into haml's code in an adventure that would've resulted in this exact method being written by me. You answered just in time for me to not reinvent the wheel, thank you!